# Lay a detail disclosure button on a UIButton

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uikit

How do I add a detail disclosure button to the right side of my text in a UIButton, perhaps using edge insets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UIButton` of Type `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` and add it as a subview of your button.

Like:

```
UIButton *mainButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mainButton setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mainButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:mainButton];

//Detail Disclosure button
UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[detailButton setFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 30, 30)];
[mainButton addSubview:detailButton];
```

Comment: Can you add it to an existing button, like say ontop of my Sign In button?

Comment: @chris: yes, instead of `mainButton` use your sign-in button's object